# In FireFox, how can I make new windows start blank with the focus in the URL bar?

Tags: firefox

In FireFox version 50 on OS X 10.10.5, when I create a new window (using ⌘-N), the new window opens with the FireFox logo and the input focus on the search field in the middle of the page:

[image]

I would really much rather prefer to start with a *blank* page and the input focus *in the URL bar*. How can I configure FireFox to behave that way?

In my FireFox Preferences, in the General tab, for "When Firefox starts" I have the setting "Show my windows and tabs from last time" and I want to keep that setting. Hopefully whatever is needed to change the ⌘-N behavior does not need to change the value of this preference setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Note:** The original answer was applicable to **Firefox** version 50, and somewhere along the way **Mozilla** added what's shown directly below. <sub>(From Firefox version 66.0.5).</sub>

**Firefox** (menu) > **Preferences… ⌘`** then click **Home** and set **Homepage and new windows** *and* **New tabs** *to:* **Blank Page**

[image: Firefox version 66.0.5.]

---

**Original Answer**

To have Firefox open a new window to a blank page, you'll need to set the Home Page to `about:blank` under General preferences (about:preferences#general in the Address bar).

[image: General preferences]

---

Then when pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, this is what a new window will look like when it opens:

[image]

Comment: I knew about this setting and **did** have this set to blank. The only thing that makes sense at this point is that the update from v. 49 to v. 50 must have changed this setting. Grrrr. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Update: `about:preferences#home` and set both selections to `Blank Page`